# Парсинг картинок C#

Tags: c#, парсер

Есть некий парсер ссылок и информации к ним. Хочу чтобы и картинки к ним тоже парсились и записывались либо ссылки на них сразу в таблицу со всей информацией, либо сразу в папку сохранялись. Ниже код, работает только часть без переменной picture и всего что связано с парсингом картинки.. увы выдается ошибка : Выполнение действия CSharp OwnCode. [Строка: 7; Cтолбец: 4] Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
Вопрос что делаю не так и как можно это подправить.

```js
HtmlElementCollection zagolovki = null;
HtmlElementCollection cennik = null;
HtmlElementCollection href = null;
HtmlElementCollection picture = null;
int a = 2;

var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"C:\Documents\parser1.xlsx"));
ExcelWorksheet tabletest = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1]; 
for(int i=1; i<5; i++) 
{
    int z = 0; 
    string ssylk = tabletest.GetValue(i,1).ToString(); 
    instance.ActiveTab.Navigate(ssylk); 
    instance.ActiveTab.WaitDownloading(); 
    zagolovki = instance.ActiveTab.FindElementsByXPath("//a[@class='head_name_item']"); 
    cennik = instance.ActiveTab.FindElementsByXPath("//span[@class='pi_price_cur']"); 
   picture = instance.ActiveTab.FindElementsByXPath("//img");
     for(int k=0; k<cennik.Count; k++) 
        {
        string zag = zagolovki.GetByNumber(z).InnerText; 
        tabletest.SetValue(a,2,zag); 
        string cen = cennik.GetByNumber(z).InnerText; 
        tabletest.SetValue(a,3,cen); 
        string ssyl = zagolovki.GetByNumber(z).GetAttribute("href"); 
        tabletest.SetValue(a,4,ssyl); 
        z++; 
        a++; 
    }
for(int k = 2; k<=tabletest.Dimension.Rows; k++) 
    {
    string strImageURL = tabletest.GetValue(k,2).ToString(); 
    string papka_save = @"C:\Documents\"; 
    string strDownloadResult = ZennoPoster.HttpGet(strImageURL,"","UTF-8",ZennoLab.InterfacesLibrary.Enums.Http.ResponceType.File,5000);
 File.Move(strDownloadResult, papka_save + new FileInfo(strDownloadResult).Name); 
 }
}
package.Save();
```

PS о существовании и возможностях использования Xpath узнала только сегодня. Знаю что реализация корявая, но хотелось бы разобраться с этим

Comment: Извините, но а как нам вам помочь, если мы даже не видим о каких "картинках" идет речь?

Comment: извините, картинки отсюда (которые в div= ''pi-foto") https:// doctorhead.ru/ catalog/ mp3-pleery/ мне важно понять как релизовать именно скачивание и привязку скаченных на локалку картинок к тому что в файле со всей информацией

Comment: Ну если `которые в div= ''pi-foto"`, то наверно не `"//img"`, а `"//a[@class='pi-foto']/img"`?